# Is it possible to change the email content in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I am new to Keycloak, my project is having keycloak as authentication server.
Currently I am developing User maintenance in my project so When new user gets created in keycloak using WEB-API, I wan to send an email to the newly created user, saying welcome to the application and please update your password.

End point: `/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email`

I am using the above endpoint to send an update password email and I am passing `UPDATE_PASSWORD` action to this endpoint.

And it is sending email correctly but I want to add **Welcome to Application** text in email template and want remove some default text from that template.

Is there any way to change keycloak template content?

Answer (score 20):

Yes this this possible you have to make the changes in the couple of files in the location `/opt/keycloak/theme` and list of files name are

1. executeActions.ftl(`/opt/keycloak/themes/base/email/html`)
2. executeActions.ftl(`/opt/keycloak/themes/base/email/text`)
3. messages_en.properties(`/opt/keycloak/themes/base/email/messages`)

Remember you have to change these files if you are using keycloak default theme ,if you added some other theme please change accordingly .

Comment: I got these themes in Keycloak ADMIN portal but not getting how to update or add new template and use it?

Comment: @Dreamer You have to update the key-value pair's value

Comment: Thank you. I Updated the existing template and it is working fine. Now I need to add new email template in existing theme.
So to add new email template, I added new .txt, .html, message to existing theme. But I am not able to use this new them in execute-action-email.

Actually I need to send 2 different email templates on execute-action-email action based on some condition.

is there any way to do this ?

Comment: @Dreamer If your query resolve accept this question and then asked a new question.

Answer (score 6):

If you want your changes to persist to Keycloak upgrades I suggest you creating a new theme that extends the theme you are using (keycloak is the default theme).

You have detailed instructions in Keycloak's [Server Development Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#creating-a-theme).

Do not forget selecting the new theme in realm's settings.