# How to give custom input for Keycloak email theme?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am using this endpoint to trigger an email in keycloak: /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email

I need to provide my own text in the email as an input. This input is variable and cannot be hardcoded in the email template provided by keycloak.

Is there a way to setup a new variable in the keycloak email template and provide that using the above mentioned API or any other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to change the email content in keycloak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349721/is-it-possible-to-change-the-email-content-in-keycloak)